# How can I use dynamic_pointer_cast with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

My goal is to have a function (foo) which takes an arbitrary number of types (`...TArgs`), and tries to cast some shared pointers (`myInt`, `myDouble` and `myChar` (see below)) to the given corresponding shared pointer types (`shared_ptr<TArgs...>`). If the cast is successful it should do some stuff, otherwise just continue running.

I tried to achieve this with using dynamic_pointer_cast on variadic template arguments. However, the concept of variadic templates and how to use them is fairly new to me. I tried to use variations of the below code but none of them worked.

How can I create a function?

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct Base {
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Int : Base{
    Int(int data) : _data(data){}
    int _data;
};
struct Double : Base{
    Double(double data) : _data(data){}
    double _data;
};
struct Char : Base{
    Char(char data) : _data(data){}
    char _data;
};


template <typename ...TArgs>
void foo(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>& ptrVec)
{
    for (const atuo& ptr : ptrVec)
    {
        if (const auto x = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<TArgs>(ptr)...) // syntax error
        {
            std::cout << "casted with value = " << x->_data << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::shared_ptr<Base> myInt = std::make_shared<Int>(1);
    const std::shared_ptr<Base> myDouble = std::make_shared<Double>(3.14);
    const std::shared_ptr<Base> myChar = std::make_shared<Char>('a');

    foo<Int>({myInt});
    std::cout << "\n";
    foo<Double, Char>({myInt, myChar});
    std::cout << "\n";
    foo<Int, Double, Char>({myInt, myChar, myDouble});
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output of the above code:

```
casted with value = 1

casted with value = a

casted with value = 1
casted with value = 3.14
casted with value = a
```

Comment: From your usage, `dynamic_cast` seems enough (and even just [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)), no need of `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Comment: But your usage is unclear: Not sure why you have `Base` in the first place...

Comment: Not sure it is what you want, but a C++17 solution is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/941afe77ceb685a3) (which can be converted to C++11 is needed).

Comment: I can't catch what the sense of the code could be. Having constants and cast them? Why? XY problem?

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks for your comment. As far as I see the code you sent seems to only  work if 2 types are provided to foo.

Comment: I only used 2 type as example (as your original snippet), with your updated example, it still [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f3d46f93e2f317) (as you might have tested yourself).

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Base>` is wrong, it would be `std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>` (for `myInt`).

Comment: a `virtual Base::Print() const` seems to avoid that "need".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, changed things a little bit. 1. I cannot use a virtual print in my actual issue, also I can only use C++14. Could you provide an answer with C++14 (you said  your previous answer could be converted to C++11)

Comment: What is your real problem? As in, *why* do you need this function?

Comment: @GáborPálovics: converted to C++11 [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7b5b2cbdb00eea7).